# Data not transferring over to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro in Excel to copy data from one worksheet to another worksheet, but not all data is being copied over.

```
Sub CopyOverBudgetRecords()

Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range
[enter image description here][1]

Set StatusCol = Sheet7.Range("E1:E14")
For Each Status In StatusCol

    If Sheet37.Range("A2") = "" Then
       Set PasteCell = Sheet37.Range("A2")
    Else
         Set PasteCell = Sheet37.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    'If Status = "Hukamnama" Then Status.Offset(0, -4).Resize(1, 5).Copy PasteCell
    'If Status = "Hukamnama" Then Status.EntireRow.Copy PasteCell
    If Status = "Hukamnama" Then Range(Status.End(xlToLeft), Status.End(xlToRight)).Copy PasteCell

    
Next Status

End Sub
```

The data copied is only pasting the first and last record to another sheet. Please can you advise me?

Data is:

[enter image description here][2]

[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/39vA5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geiQD.png)

Comment: Where is the data that is not getting copied?

Comment: The data is in a worksheet

Comment: The code is only copying the first and last record

Comment: Without seeing the data it seems hopeless.  Update your question showing test data if you would like additional help

Comment: The data I am focusing on is only in column E and the condition of  on  = "Hukamnama" data

Comment: Daniel, I've added an image of the data to the post

Comment: Thanks.  Could you also please attach an image of what sheet37 results look like after running the code that you have?

Comment: Results added Daniel

Comment: The issue stems from not having any data in the first row, more specifically A1, on sheet37 when you run the macro.  When A1 is empty and after your first run that fills A2, running `Else Set PasteCell = Sheet37.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)` code will set PasteCell to A3 for every subsequent loop overwriting row 3 each time.  This is because when you run Range("A1").End(xlDown) on the empty A1 cell it will only go as far down as to the next cell with data which is now A2.  Then applying the Offset(1,0) gives you A3.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult without seeing the contents of the book. maybe something like this?

```
Option Explicit
Dim sh7 As Worksheet, sh37 As Worksheet
Dim StatusCol As Range, Status As Range, PasteCell As Range
Sub CopyOverBudgetRecords()
    Set sh7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7")
    Set sh37 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet37")
    Set StatusCol = sh7.Range("E1:E14")
    
    For Each Status In StatusCol
        If Status.Value = "Hukamnama" Then
            sh7.Range(Status.End(xlToLeft), Status.End(xlToRight)).Copy sh37.Cells(fUltimafila, 1)
        End If
    Next Status
End Sub
Private Function fUltimafila() As Long
    If sh37.Cells(2, 5) = vbNullString Then
        fUltimafila = 2
    Else
        fUltimafila = sh37.Cells(sh37.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Run Time Error 91   If sh37.Cells(2, 5) = vbNullString Then

Comment: are you using the full code?

Comment: I've copy the block over to a new module